# Como integrar uma tabela do banco de dados a outra?

Tags: banco-de-dados

**Exemplo:** Um sistema que registra clientes, compras e produtos, cada um em uma tabela diferente. Tendo um registro de compras que deve possuir os campos:

- Cliente: indica qual cliente já cadastrado (em outra tabela do banco) que efetuou a compra.
- Produtos: seleciona qual foi o produto (que também está em outra tabela) que foi vendido para o cliente.

Além disso devo colocar outros campos como data de venda etc, mas isso não vem ao caso, pois quero saber como faço essa integração entre tabelas? Pegar o registro de outra tabela e associar a um campo de um registro de outra tabela. Já tentei pesquisar sobre isso mas não consegui encontrar, se me derem um exemplo de como funcionaria ou termos que devo pesquisar eu agradeceria.

Peço que não ponham muito código em linguagem do banco de dados, pois não entendo nada disso, os bancos que crio são totalmente visuais, ou seja, criados automaticamente pelo Visual Studio.

**Detalhes**: Deveria funcionar da seguinte maneira, ao querer registrar uma compra, o usuário informaria a data da venda (essa parte eu sei como faz), o cliente que comprou aquilo (esse cliente tem um registro em outra tabela então deve-se buscar e associar o nome do cliente ao seus dados armazenados na outra tabela) e por fim o produto vendido (que também possui registro em outra tabela)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A integração entre tabelas normalmente é feita por [**chaves estrangeiras**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chave_estrangeira). Uma chave estrangeira relaciona uma chave primária de uma tabela com a chave primária de outra tabela. Isto garante [a integridade referencial](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integridade_referencial) entre tabelas.

Para o seu exemplo, uma compra deve relacionar produtos com um cliente. O ideal seria haver uma tabela associativa entre produtos e uma compra, tendo um campo adicional, o de quantidade. Ou seja, esta tabela associativa deve ter, além de sua chave primária, duas chaves estrangeiras, sendo uma apontando para uma compra e outra apontando para o produto que pertence a uma compra.

Comment: Valeu, deu pra entender um pouco e saber o que devo pesquisar agora pra fazer isso. No meu caso seria a tabela compra com duas chaves estrangeiras, uma apontando para cliente e outra para produto (a quantidade não é tão necessária na tabela compra, quando um elemento de produto for atribuído na tabela compra eu coloco pra diminuir uma quantidade daquele produto na tabela produto). Então devo transformar o campo Nome na tabela cliente e produto como chave primária né? Meio complicado isso hein kk vou dar uma pesquisada no youtube

Comment: Bom, eu fiz aqui no Visual Studio, mas não consegui distinguir de uma tabela normal, o campo Cliente aceitou um nome que não tinha na minha tabela cliente, o mesmo aconteceu com o produto..

Comment: O campo `Nome` não é uma boa alternativa como chave primária por ser um `varchar`, possivelmente. Chaves primárias e estrangeiras não podem ser fáceis de serem modificadas. Por mais que você diga que não vai ser modificado, há também o problema de `varchar` ser mais caro em custo de operação do banco de dados, para conferir valor, selecionar, inserir, atualizar... Sugiro fazer outra pergunta com a nova dúvida.